# Mongo Query Time Duration

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a mongo query like this

```
aggregate([
    {
        "$geoNear": {
            "near": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 35.709770973477255 , 51.404043066431775 ] },
            "distanceField": "dist.calculated",
            "maxDistance": 5000,
            "spherical": True,
            "query": { "active_delivery_categories": { "$in" : ["biker"]}, "ban_status": False},
            "num": 100
        }
    }
])
```

when i add new filed to my query like this:

```
"query": { "availability_status":"idle","active_delivery_categories": { "$in" : ["biker"]}, "ban_status": False}
```

response time grow doubles

it happen just on this filed

for example on this query it not happen!

```
"query": { "city":"London","active_delivery_categories": { "$in" : ["biker"]}, "ban_status": False}
```

do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

One possibility that I can think of is as follows... your original query is able to make use of an appropriate index, and is therefore fast. With the added condition, it is not able to use the index, and is therefore slower.

Look at the .explain() output to see if this is so.

But then, I also notice that you have said it happens only by adding this field. Are you sure of that?

Comment: i dont have any index on fields. yes i am sure , i tested it too much